# Sign extending from 8 bits into 16 bit register to get 0xff00

Tags: assembly, binary, xilinx

I am working on a 'simple cpu' project in xilinx and need to store the value 0xFF00 in a register but the assembler command is capable of passing only 8 bits worth of data at a time.

The remainder bits are filled via sign extension.

So 0xFF becomes 0xFFFF and 0x0F is just F (0x000F).

Is there a simple way to achieve FF00? Or would I need more computational logic. The cpu is capable of all the logic functions, adding, subbing and roling the bits to the left.

Comment: That's 16 bits, decide if you want 12 or 16.

Comment: 16, my mistake was thinking of the operand of the function

Comment: What is your ISA? What instruction did you use? Do you maybe have something like a load upper?

Comment: 0xFF00 can't be the result of 8->16-bit sign extension, because the high byte isn't copies of the top bit of the low byte.  I was going to tag this [tag:sign-extension], but it sounds like it's actually about constructing arbitrary 16-bit constants in 2 halves, outside the -128 .. 127 range (assuming a 2's complement interpretation of the bit-pattern).  Or are you saying you only have a `mov reg16, sign_extended_imm8` for mov-immediate, and want to get 0xFF00 somehow?

Comment: One obvious possibility is `mov reg, 0xFF80` and `add reg,reg` to left-shift by 1.  (i.e. `mov reg, -128` and double it to `-256` with a left-shift or add to itself.)  IDK what actual mnemonics you have, but presumably mov and add are self-explanatory.

Comment: I can add logic to the hardware/instructions but should not need to.  I dont know how to easiest describe/show the functions I have

Comment: @Vanseci Why not zero register (e.g. xor), load the byte (resulting in `0x00ff`), then `NOT` the register (resulting in `0xff00`)? If you have a "load-byte-with-zero-extension" instruction, it turns into two steps (`LDBZX` followed by `NOT`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're saying you only have something like `mov reg16, sign_extended_imm8`, and you want to create FF00 which isn't possible directly with a sign-extended 8-bit number.

**0x80 sign-extends to 0xFF80**, which is one left-shift away from the value you want.

```
mov reg, 0xFF80           # or mov reg, -128
add reg, reg              # shift left by 1, giving FF00
```

Answer (score -2):

I went with storing 0x7C and rolling 6 bits to the left.

It takes longer than required but at least generates the right output.

The result is F800 but it is still a shade of red that is fit for purpose.

Comment: Anything wrong with Peter's suggestion in the comments? (Load `0x80` to get `0xFF80` then add to itself to get `0xFF00`)